# Hibernate Annotation relations does not work with spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am creating some simple Spring Boot project with Hibernate JPA. 
I created some data model which consists 5 tables for now and created entities reflecting tables. I have set `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true` and my entities was correctly reflected by schema created in PostgreSQL.

Next step was to start adding relations.

Part of my assumed datamodel is (paron my UML)

[image]

Very simple one to many relation.

My entities look that way (getters and setters omitted below, exist in code):

```
@Entity
public class AppUser {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  private String name;
  private String secondName;
  private String email;
  private java.util.Date joinDate;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_role_id")
  private UserRole userRole;
}


@Entity
public class UserRole {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  private String roleName;
}
```

I launch my application with `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true` and column `user_role_id` gets created in `AppUser` table but application fails to start due errors:

```
2018-10-11 19:41:35.435  INFO 45564 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2018-10-11 19:41:35.466  WARN 45564 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
2018-10-11 19:41:35.466 ERROR 45564 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: column t1.tgconstrname does not exist
```

There is full stacktrace (please advise if should paste it here instead of pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/x4qNJkK9

When I set `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false` application starts succesfully.

Any ideas why is that happening?

Comment: You can try to use the @Column(name="user_role_id") on the UserRole Table.

Comment: Could not it be that something already exists in the PostgreSQL schema what would interfere with the table creation by spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true? Would it be possible to try with a new virgin Postgres SQL schema?

Comment: @Michal I tried this on pristine database, and now tried again with new schema. Still no luck

Comment: @GrinishNepal Hey. I am not sure how to understand that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: what I am saying is give a column name to your ID column in UserRole.  Just paste the annotation after the @GeneratedValue and work with a pristine Postgre