# Relation and differences between spring.jpa.generate-ddl and spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

For a `Spring Boot` app (2.4.1) working with `Spring Data JPA`, with `@Entity` classes based with the `javax.persistence` annotations. For a `application.properties` exists these two properties:

- `spring.jpa.generate-ddl`
- `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto`

Thanks to STS, the following descriptions are available:

**spring.jpa.generate-ddl**

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl
java.lang.Boolean

Default: false

Whether to initialize the schema on startup.
```

**spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto
java.lang.String

DDL mode. This is actually a shortcut for the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" property. 
Defaults to "create-drop" when using an embedded database and no schema manager was detected. 
Otherwise, defaults to "none"
```

- When is used the `spring.jpa.generate-ddl`?
- When is mandatory use the `spring.jpa.generate-ddl` approach? What scenario?

I did realise that it is ignored and really is mandatory use `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto`, it for the following scenario:

- For the `H2` in-memory database - the schema is created through the `schema.sql` file  and defining the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property as **none**, then in this case `spring.jpa.generate-ddl` is totally ignored.

**Question**:

- What is the relation (if exists) and differences between `spring.jpa.generate-ddl` and `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto`?

I found these posts, and in someway is not clear when is mandatory use `spring.jpa.generate-ddl`

- [H2 schema still generated when spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55575505/h2-schema-still-generated-when-spring-jpa-generate-ddl-false)
- [Hibernate Annotation relations does not work with spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52766163/hibernate-annotation-relations-does-not-work-with-spring-jpa-generate-ddl-true)
- [tables not creating in spring boot v2.2.6.RELEASE postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60989934/tables-not-creating-in-spring-boot-v2-2-6-release-postgres)

Answer (score 4):

In this [Spring Boot Database Initialization](https://springhow.com/spring-boot-database-initialization/) article you can find the differences well explained.

Just to summarize they are pretty much used for the same goal. The goal is to define the behaviour of your application after any modification on your entity classes. Given that, The first one permits you generic choices instead the second one permits you to decide within a pool of behaviours.

(I would define just one of them also to avoid conflicts.)

So:

> 1. spring.jpa.generate-ddl – This configuration takes a boolean value to either enable or disable schema initialization.

So imagine that you are adding/removing a field in the entity User: In this case:

- true: it will change your schema automatically when you run the app
- false: no changes on the schema. App will fail if some call are made to the unsync entity/db.

> 2. spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto – This property takes an enum that controls the schema generation in a more controlled way.

Here is the interesting part, there are more scenarios based on your choice:

- none : same behaviour of "false" of generate-ddl
- create : drop the last schema of and create a new one. It drops the data too so be sure not to use that in prod.
- create-drop : same of the "create" option but the scheam is destroyed at the shutdown and not at the next run of your application.
- validate : the app check the Entities element and the DB. If there are inconsistencies then gives you back some Exception.
- update : here, in case of a new column for example, the application doesn’t create the entire table. It will adds the new column and creates a unique index.

Everything is explained (better) in the article with a proper image to show you! Enjoy!

P.S.

If you are trying to find the difference also between *spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto* and *hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto* please check this other [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63641919/what-is-the-difference-between-ddl-auto-and-hbm2ddl-auto)

> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto This is actually a shortcut for the "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" property.

Comment: Once I read the answer and post, if is correct - I am going to mark it as valid

Comment: The statement ```"But bear in mind that the spring.jpa.generate-ddl will be ignored if you have a config for spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto. This is because the second config is more fine-grained and thus overriding the first one."``` from that article is not true based on my testing. I have the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` and `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true`, it still creates the table while starting the application. And the Spring version is 3.1.1.